# Switching views on ios

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, ios, xcode

I have a story board that have 4 screens

welcome
sign up 
sign in 
dashboard

on welcome screen there are two buttons

sign up 
sign in

i want when user click the sign in then it will move to that screen both the other 2 screen have there own classes

so if user sign up or sign in then it will move to the dashboard by check the user name and passowrd is correct i am using the php/mysql on the backend

so i want to know that either i need the coustom segue or the other thing need to be done ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the structure of your app. Depending on how your app is setup and the app type, you would either :

- dismiss the login/sign up modal view on success
- Push the next view onto the navigation controller

If you're using a navigation controller, then on successful login/sign up, do something like :

```
UIViewController *dashboard = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dashboard];
```

If your login screen is being presented as a modal view controller, then you need to simply dismiss it, but based on your question I'd say you're more likely using something like a navigation controller. If you're using neither then you'd need something slightly different but you'd need to give more detail on that

Comment: the identifer means the identifier for the segue ?

Comment: The identifier of the view itself. In interface builder, you can assign identifiers to the views, which you then use to instantiate it as I've shown :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Manually Triggered segues,

When user clicks on signin button, connect a manually triggered segue between sigin button and another class.

Use below code:

```
 //do necessary validations
 if([validations isEqualToString:@"true"]){
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SignInTonextPage" sender: self];

    }
```

Comment: by manually you mean to use custom segue ? and what will be written on validation like if the current class name is welcomeViewController and other is SigninViewController